# How to get keyboard to popup when UITabBar item is tapped

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController, in which one of the views is a MFMailComposeViewController.

Is there any way I can get the keyboard to show when the tab for this view is tapped, rather than the text field for the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MFMailComposeViewController inherits from UIResponder, you should be able to call:

```
[myMailComposeViewController becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I made the UITextField first responder, and it works like a champ!

Thank you very much!